# Google Maps API v3 in internet explorer 9 doesn't load

Tags: jquery, google-maps, dojo, internet-explorer-9

I am having an issue loading Google Maps API V3 in internet explorer.  Here's a list of things that I've done already:

1. Checked out this [link](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21849), because apparently Google's heard complaints from IE users before.  None of these things solved my problem.
2. Tested maps.google.com from IE9.  It works fine from there, but my page does not.
3. The web designer said that she could intermittently get it to load in IE.  I never was able to.  So it seems somewhat random.
4. I killed everything in my code *except* for the google maps stuff, and it still didn't fly.
5. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148058/google-maps-api-v3-internet-explorer), which says that it might have a problem with misplaced commas in the code.  I don't have any of those.  I do make extensive use of jquery and dojo, but I wouldn't imagine that would be an issue, would it?
6. Of course, it works fine in Chrome,FF,Safari, etc.  It's just an issue with IE9.

Anybody have any thoughts?

Here's the content from my initialize function, which is called once the body loads.

```
      var map;


      function initialize() {

        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.97, -94.72),
          zoom: 13,
          scaleControl:true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a demo of the issue? The code will not help much, it's OK like it is.

Comment: Here's a link to a rough demo of it on our test server: https://mapstest.lenexa.com/commdevmap/browser_base.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the meta-tag for  compatibility-mode and set it to IE7. Set it to IE8